# Sequential processing of asynchronous tasks

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Assume the following synchronous code:

```
try
{
    Foo();
    Bar();
    Fubar();
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
}
catch(Exception e) // For illustration purposes only. Catch specific exceptions!
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Now assume all these methods have an Async counterpart and I have to use those for some reason, so simply wrapping the whole thing in a new task is not an option.
How would I achieve the same behavior?
What I mean with "same" is:

1. Execute a handler for the exception, if one is thrown.
2. Stop execution of the following methods, if an exception is thrown.

The only thing I was able to come up with is ***horrible***:

```
var fooTask = FooAsync();
fooTask.ContinueWith(t => HandleError(t.Exception),
                     TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
fooTask.ContinueWith(
    t =>
    {
        var barTask = BarAsync();
        barTask.ContinueWith(t => HandleError(t.Exception),
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        barTask.ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                var fubarTask = FubarAsync();
                fubarTask.ContinueWith(t => HandleError(t.Exception),
                                       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                fubarTask.ContinueWith(
                    t => Console.WriteLine("All done"),
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
            }, 
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Please note:

- I need a solution that works with .NET 4, so `async/await` is out of the question. However, if it would work with `async/await` feel free to show how.
- I don't need to use the TPL. If it is impossible with the TPL another approach would be OK, maybe with Reactive Extensions?

Comment: Don't suppose it'd be possible to write a helper method that takes a `params Action[]` parameter along with a complete/error handler from which it it builds all this nastiness for you?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Good idea. That's what I am going to do if there is no "real" solution...

Comment: You also need to add a continuation for each task to handle `Canceled`, if any of the tasks are cancelable.

Comment: @Servy: Let's assume they can't be cancelled.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It wouldn't be an `Action[]`, it would be a `Task[]`.  Basically a `ForEachAsync` that incorporated exception handling.

Comment: @Servy No, it actually would be a `Func<Task>[]`, because the tasks should only be started when the previous was successfully completed.

Comment: @Servy Yeah I suppose; I just figured the "helper" method wouldn't care and just pass in any old action/lambda call and do the `Task` stuff for you internally, especially if you don't want the outside callers to add fluff/stuff to the task's `ContinueWith` or other members. (this could be useful too though, could just have overloads for both)

Comment: This just seems like a convoluted way of making your asynchronous methods synchronous. If this is the case, why make them asynchronous to begin with?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It would need to be a `Func<Task>` because the helper method needs the task to be able to wire up the continuation.  Without that you'd need to wrap the work in a `StartNew`, and that would be bad as you're needlessly blocking a thread pool thread for the duration.

Comment: @Ginosaji They're orthogonal concepts.  It's actually a common and appropriate use case to execute a number of asynchronous operations sequentially.  The idea is that you're not keeping a thread busy by having it do a blocking wait on each operation.  It's the entire premise of the 5.0 `async/await` functionality.

Comment: @Ginosaji: Not synchronous. Just sequential.

Comment: How does this differ from executing the three synchronous methods on a single background thread, though? There's no blocking wait in either situation.

Comment: @Ginosaji: As I said in the question, I can't do that. The simplest reason for this is that the API I am using only offers Async methods.

Comment: Sadly with 4.0 I've been stuck doing basically the same thing you've got up there.  I did add a helper method to clean up the wire-up code, but yeah, it's ugly.

Comment: @Ginosaji You're assuming that the tasks all represent CPU bound work.  That's only a subset of async operations.  You also need to consider async IO as another large example.  While that task is "running" no thread needs to be running it at all.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I hope you are just adjusting your answer. I don't think it should be deleted, it *is* one possible workaround.

Comment: @Servy: I understand now. Thank you for the explanation. I have some thoughts on how to solve this. I'll see if I can't turn them into something tangible later this evening. (Also lol @ people complaining about being stuck with .NET 4.0. Our lead developers refuse to use anything past .NET 3.5 here).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yeah I did, mostly because I thought it was _incorrect_ in that it did not provide the desired behaviour, but I adjusted and undeleted it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's how it would work with `async`:

```
try
{
    await FooAsync();
    await BarAsync();
    await FubarAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
}
catch(Exception e) // For illustration purposes only. Catch specific exceptions!
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

This would work on .NET 4.0 if you installed the (prerelease) [Microsoft.Bcl.Async package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

---

Since you're stuck on VS2010, you can use a variant of [Stephen Toub's `Then`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx):

```
public static Task Then(this Task first, Func<Task> next)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  first.ContinueWith(_ =>
  {
    if (first.IsFaulted) tcs.TrySetException(first.Exception.InnerExceptions);
    else if (first.IsCanceled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    else
    {
      try
      {
        next().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
          if (t.IsFaulted) tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
          else if (t.IsCanceled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
          else tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
      }
      catch (Exception exc) { tcs.TrySetException(exc); }
    }
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
  return tcs.Task; 
}
```

You can use it as such:

```
var task = FooAsync().Then(() => BarAsync()).Then(() => FubarAsync());
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
  if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
  {
    var e = t.Exception.InnerException;
    // exception handling
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
  }
}, TaskContinuationOptions.ExcecuteSynchronously);
```

---

Using Rx, it would look like this (assuming you don't have the `async` methods already exposed as `IObservable<Unit>`):

```
FooAsync().ToObservable()
    .SelectMany(_ => BarAsync().ToObservable())
    .SelectMany(_ => FubarAsync().ToObservable())
    .Subscribe(_ => { Console.WriteLine("All done"); },
        e => { Console.WriteLine(e); });
```

I think. I'm not an Rx master, by any means. :)

Comment: @StephenCleary: Any ideas about an alternate way with .NET 4?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Stephen Toub has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx) that would be helpful here; he implements a `Then` extension method for more natural sequential chaining of asynchronous methods.

Comment: In the implementation of Then, there is an undefined variable t.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of completeness, that's how I would implement the helper method suggested by Chris Sinclair:

```
public void RunSequential(Action onComplete, Action<Exception> errorHandler,
                          params Func<Task>[] actions)
{
    RunSequential(onComplete, errorHandler,
                  actions.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
}

public void RunSequential(Action onComplete, Action<Exception> errorHandler,
                          IEnumerator<Func<Task>> actions)
{
    if(!actions.MoveNext())
    {
        onComplete();
        return;
    }

    var task = actions.Current();
    task.ContinueWith(t => errorHandler(t.Exception),
                      TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    task.ContinueWith(t => RunSequential(onComplete, errorHandler, actions),
                      TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

This ensures that each subsequent task is only requested when the previous one completed successfully.
It assumes that the `Func<Task>` returns an already running task.

Comment: I think something finally clicked up there for me if you know what I mean. Thanks for the implementation/question!

Answer (score 5):

What you have here is essentially a `ForEachAsync`.  You want to run each async item, sequentially, but with some error handling support.  Here is one such implementation:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync(IEnumerable<Func<Task>> tasks)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    Task currentTask = Task.FromResult(false);

    foreach (Func<Task> function in tasks)
    {
        currentTask.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        currentTask.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetCanceled()
                , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
        Task<Task> continuation = currentTask.ContinueWith(t => function()
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        currentTask = continuation.Unwrap();
    }

    currentTask.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    currentTask.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetCanceled()
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
    currentTask.ContinueWith(t => tcs.TrySetResult(true)
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I added in support for canceled tasks as well, just to be more general and because it took so little to do.

It adds each task as a continuation of the previous task, and all along the line it ensures that any exceptions result in the final task's exception being set.

Here is an example usage:

```
public static Task FooAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started Foo");
    return Task.Delay(1000)
        .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Finished Foo"));
}

public static Task BarAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Func<Task>> list = new List<Func<Task>>();

    list.Add(() => FooAsync());
    list.Add(() => FooAsync());
    list.Add(() => FooAsync());
    list.Add(() => FooAsync());
    list.Add(() => BarAsync());

    Task task = ForEachAsync(list);

    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.ToString())
        , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Done!")
        , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

Comment: Would not call this sequential execution of async tasks in my terminology. This is sequential starting of async tasks, but there is nothing in there that ensures that they execute one after another, which what sequential execution means in my head.

Comment: @GudlaugurEgilsson But that's exactly what this does.  Each is added as a continuation of the other, so the second can't start until the first finishes, the third can't start until the second finishes, etc.

Comment: I stand corrected, after trying this out again, this works exactly like I hoped. Seems like the problem was in the tasks I was using to test this. Thanks! P.S. renaming "function" to "taskRunner" would enhance the readability of this code tremendously ;-)

Comment: When incorporating this in my tests, I discovered that this method of wrapping the loop into continuation tasks, results in the aggregate task always getting cancelled if a subtask throws an exception. This can be corrected by changing the second to last line in the foreach loop to this:    
`Task<Task> continuation = currentTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        {
            return t;
        }
        return function();
    });`

Comment: @GudlaugurEgilsson The *goal* of the process is to ensure that no further operations run when there is an exception or cancellation.  I explicitly go out of my way to do that.  One simply needs to remove the cancellation/faulted continuations and make the continuation that fires the next task unconditional if you don't want that behavior.

Comment: The problem is not that they are run, the problem is that the TaskCompletionSource always gets a cancelled status, probably because subsequent tasks after the one that throws, are cancelled. By checking the status inside the continuation and returning the faulted/cancelled task, no more tasks are wrapped that need cancelling. Remember that the loop always creates an unwrapped task for every "function" in the list, even if "function" is only called once due to the first task failing.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a method to combine two tasks, and only start the second if the first succeeds.

```
public static Task Then(this Task parent, Task next)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    parent.ContinueWith(pt =>
    {
        if (pt.IsFaulted)
        {
            tcs.SetException(pt.Exception.InnerException);
        }
        else
        {
            next.ContinueWith(nt =>
            {
                if (nt.IsFaulted)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(nt.Exception.InnerException);
                }
                else { tcs.SetResult(null); }
            });
            next.Start();
        }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

you can then chain tasks together:

```
Task outer = FooAsync()
    .Then(BarAsync())
    .Then(FubarAsync());

outer.ContinueWith(t => {
    if(t.IsFaulted) {
        //handle exception
    }
});
```

If your tasks are started immediately you can just wrap them in a `Func`:

```
public static Task Then(this Task parent, Func<Task> nextFunc)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    parent.ContinueWith(pt =>
    {
        if (pt.IsFaulted)
        {
            tcs.SetException(pt.Exception.InnerException);
        }
        else
        {
            Task next = nextFunc();
            next.ContinueWith(nt =>
            {
                if (nt.IsFaulted)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(nt.Exception.InnerException);
                }
                else { tcs.SetResult(null); }
            });
        }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just like the answer from Chris Sinclair, yours assumes that the tasks returned from the methods are not started. For most APIs, that is not true. The are already started inside the method. So, in your code - and in Chris' - the tasks run in parallel. And the whole thing will error out as soon as the first task is finished, because than it tries to start a task that is already running or finished.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Sorry, I didn't read his answer before posting. The obvious thing to do is just to use a `Func<Task>` instead, then you can do `FooAsync().Then(BarAsync).Then(FubarAsync)`.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I also did in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I haven't really used the TPL much, so this is just a stab in the dark. And given what @Servy mentioned, perhaps this won't run completely asynchronously. But I figured I'd post it and if it's *way* off the mark, you can downvote me to oblivion or I can have it deleted (or we can just fix what needs fixing)

```
public void RunAsync(Action onComplete, Action<Exception> errorHandler, params Action[] actions)
{
    if (actions.Length == 0)
    {
        //what to do when no actions/tasks provided?
        onComplete();
        return;
    }

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(actions.Length);
    foreach(var action in actions)
    {
        Task task = new Task(action);
        task.ContinueWith(t => errorHandler(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    //last task calls onComplete
    tasks[actions.Length - 1].ContinueWith(t => onComplete(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    //wire all tasks to execute the next one, except of course, the last task
    for (int i = 0; i <= actions.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        var nextTask = tasks[i + 1];
        tasks[i].ContinueWith(t => nextTask.Start(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }

    tasks[0].Start();
}
```

And it would have usage like:

```
RunAsync(() => Console.WriteLine("All done"),
            ex => Console.WriteLine(ex),
            Foo,
            Bar,
            Fubar);
```

Thoughts? Downvotes? :)

(I definitely prefer async/await though)

EDIT: Based on your comments to take `Func<Task>`, would this be a proper implementation?

```
public void RunAsync(Action onComplete, Action<Exception> errorHandler, params Func<Task>[] actions)
{
    if (actions.Length == 0)
    {
        //what to do when no actions/tasks provided?
        onComplete();
        return;
    }

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(actions.Length);
    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        Func<Task> nextActionFunc = action;
        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            var nextTask = nextActionFunc();
            nextTask.ContinueWith(t => errorHandler(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            nextTask.Start();
        });
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    //last task calls onComplete
    tasks[actions.Length - 1].ContinueWith(t => onComplete(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    //wire all tasks to execute the next one, except of course, the last task
    for (int i = 0; i <= actions.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        var nextTask = tasks[i + 1];
        tasks[i].ContinueWith(t => nextTask.Start(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }

    tasks[0].Start();
}
```

Comment: That won't work in my scenario, because all I have are methods that return an *already running* task. So there is no synchronous action I could wrap in a new task. So your method really would need to take a `params Func<Task>[]` and work with that.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth What if the method took in `Task` instead of `Action`?

Comment: Wouldn't help, because that means all tasks would already be running at the time of the call to `RunAsync`, which is exactly what I *don't* want.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth As said in comments earlier, you should take in a `Func<Task>`.  That function could return an already running task, or start a new task and return it.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, that's exactly what I am saying ;-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I updated the answer with a new implementation. Sorry again if it's off the mark (I'm mostly just guessing if this is correct. It executes in LINQPad just fine, but I'm not sure if it's asynchronous the way you expect it to be)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: No, it is not. It still iterates the tasks in one go. It seems to assume that the tasks returned by the delegates are not started. In my scenario - and in most, I guess - this is not the case. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14631799/572644) on how it works for me. Your solution will run the tasks in parallel and error out as soon as the first task is finished as it tries to start a task that is already running or finished.