# Http PostAsync without Execution

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, task

i am working on a pretty simple project, i am trying to build a List of Tasks,
to be precise a List of HttpPost Tasks.

I have following method for posting data:

```
 public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsyncJson<T>(string uri, T o)
 {
    return this.PutAsync<T>(uri, o, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = JsonSettings });
 }
```

where PutAsync is the Base Method of the .NET HttpClient

Now i simply put the tasks in a List, therefore i use following code:

```
List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> tasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
List.Add(PutAsyncJson("url", obj1));
List.Add(PutAsyncJson("url", obj2));
```

After all tasks have been added to the list i want them to execute in a serial way.
My problem now is that the task already get executed when i add them to the list.
Why are they already executed there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequential processing of asynchronous tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630770/sequential-processing-of-asynchronous-tasks).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's the way that `Task`s work; they start executing immediately. If you want to defer execution of the tasks, you could consider making a list of task *creator* delegates instead:

```
var tasks = new List<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>> {
    () => PutAsyncJson("url", obj1),
    () => PutAsyncJson("url", obj2)
};
```

Comment: How do you think the [link I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630770/sequential-processing-of-asynchronous-tasks) wasn't a correct duplicate?

Comment: ok, i thought the would only start if i await them or request the .Result Property

Comment: @DavidG: it seems the essence of the question is why the tasks start running immediately, not how to run them in sequence.

Comment: The sentence *After all tasks have been added to the list i want them to execute in a serial way* suggests otherwise. Anyway, that duplicate achieves both things.

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth: yep, that's a common misconception. All that accessing `.Result` does is ensure all the async parts of the tasks complete resuming the thread's execution.

Comment: well i thought if i do not await the result the task will not be executed at all

Comment: Salient line from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx): "Because tasks typically run asynchronously on a thread pool thread, the thread that creates and starts the task continues execution as soon as the task has been instantiated."