# Multiple task execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've faced with problem about  execution of  the following method. Main  purpose is  that this two task  should be executed sequentially. But  when  i  execute  this  method  I get  System.AggregateException.

```
 public Task<StockOptionData> GetOptionDataAsync(Stream str, Stock stck)
    {
        Task<StockOptionData> res; //second task /result task 
        Task<string> text; // first task 
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str))
        {
            // Part 1 
            text = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

       // Part  2
        res = text.ContinueWith((i) =>
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                FullStockInfo info = ser.Deserialize<FullStockInfo>(i.Result);


                StockOptionData datas = new StockOptionData(info);
                return datas;
            });

        return res;

    }
```

There  is error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'SslStream'.
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.IO.Stream.<>c.b__43_1(Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   ...

Exception occured  only when I use the async version of this method.  The  execution  with single tread works correctly. The question is  that,  where is my mistake? What  is  the best  way to  execute  multiple tasks that has different results sequentially?

Comment: Why are you not calling `await` on the reader when you read the data?

Comment: And why are you using `ContinueWith()` instead of just using `await`? Your code is needlessly complicated for no gain.

Comment: It look like you are getting ObjectDisposedException as inner exception, which means you are disposing the reader before you task kicks off. Tasks does not guarantees to kick off immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More simple and clear.

You use `await` the `Task` to wait for the operation of reading to complete. When it finishes, the code continues to run `Deserialize`

```
public async Task<StockOptionData> GetOptionDataAsync(Stream str, Stock stck)
{
    string myTextString  = "";
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str))
    {
        myTextString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    FullStockInfo info = ser.Deserialize<FullStockInfo>(myTextString);
    StockOptionData datas = new StockOptionData(info);
    return datas;
}
```

This is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630770/sequential-processing-of-asynchronous-tasks) of how to execute a list of task sequentially

Comment: myTextString scope ends at the closing bracket of the using block.

Comment: I prefer this solution, but it won't work unless the user adds the `async` keyword  to the method signature.

Comment: completed the answer

Comment: These codes of Deserialize run synch. That means: with or without Task, you have to wait for his execution anyway. So why we need to put them in Task?

Comment: Code works  .  But  The question  is  in general  ,  How to  execute two or more  asynchronous  tasks  sequentially  .  That is why i've created  Part2 inside  another task  .

Comment: @ThierryV Thank for  answer  .  Link that i take from your answer  was helpful
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/11/21/processing-sequences-of-asynchronous-operations-with-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this method isn't asynchronous. Try adding the `async` keyword to the method and `await` any asynchronous operations.

See Thierry V's answer for the implementation...

Comment: @xxbbcc: I agree with the assessment, but I was simply giving the user a "short answer."

Comment: @xxbbcc await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); return a `string`. How can a string can ContinueWith ?

Comment: text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); 
But  this part is not working  . 
My main question is that  how executes two (or  more ) tasks  sequentially   . That is why i use  ContinueWith .

Comment: @Thierry V: You are correct. I will point him to your answer.