# Why doesn't it work to use ContinueWith to run task sequentially?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

My goal was to start "Task2" after "Task1". At first I wrote code like "Code1" below, but it did not work (Task2 started before Task1 was finished). So I searched Stackoverflow and modified my code like "Code2" below as [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14630968/455796) suggested. I wonder why "Code1" did not work.

Code1

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Test2();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    void Test2()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await Task1();
        }).ContinueWith((t) => {
            Task2();
        });
    }

    async Task Task1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 starting....");
        await LongTask();
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 done");
    }

    Task LongTask()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        });            
    }

    void Task2()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 2");
    }
```

Code2

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await Task1();
            Task2();
        }).ContinueWith((t) => {
            //Task2();
        });
```

Comment: I think this article holds the explanation: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/potential-pitfalls-to-avoid-when-passing-around-async-lambdas/

Comment: Although I think the simplest solution to your problem would be to change `Test2` to `async void Test2() { await Task1(); Task2(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you are running task like `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => ...` it returns `Task<Task>` (task of task). And first task terminates without waiting for the inner `Task`.

For preventing this situation, you can use `Unwrap` method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task1();
})
.Unwrap()
.ContinueWith((t) => {
    Task2();
});
```

That `StartNew` will return `Task<Task>`, and it seems you want to execute continuation after inner task completion. That's why we need `Unwrap`.
It  “unwraps” the inner task that’s returned as the result of the outer task.  Calling Unwrap on a Task gives you back a new Task (which we often refer to as a proxy) which represents the eventual completion of the inner task. And then, we are adding continuation to the inner task.

But, as `Task.Run` will do that unwrapping automatically you can use `Task.Run` in that case:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task1();
})
.ContinueWith((t) => {
    Task2();
});
```

And that can be simplified to:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task1();
    Task2();
});
```

***Detailed information about diferences between `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`:***

Read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) from Stephen Toub who is an engineer in the .Net team. The reason of decision in case of `Task.Run`:

> Because we expect it to be so common for folks to want to offload work
> to the ThreadPool, and for that work to use `async/await`, we decided to
> build this unwrapping functionality into `Task.Run`.

By the way, as Stephen recommended just try to use `Task.Run` in most cases, but  this in no way obsoletes `Task.Factory.StartNew`, there is still some places in which `Task.Factory.StartNew` must be used:

> `Task.Factory.StartNew` still has many important (albeit more advanced)
> uses.  You get to control `TaskCreationOptions` for how the task
> behaves.  You get to control the scheduler for where the task should
> be queued to and run.  You get to use overloads that accept object
> state, which for performance-sensitive code paths can be used to avoid
> closures and the corresponding allocations.  For the simple cases,
> though, `Task.Run` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` don't understand async lambdas. For `Task.Factory.StartNew` your lambda is just function returning `Task`. It doesn't automatically await that task. Also, note that using `Task.Factory.StarNew` and `ContinueWith` is discouraged in modern C# as it hard to use correctly (please read, "StartNew is Dangerous" by Stephen Cleary). You should use `Task.Factory.StarNew` or `ContinueWith` only if you can't do without them.

Instead, you can just use async/await one more time:

```
async Task Test2()
{
    await Task1();
    Task2();
}
```

or `Task.Run`:

```
async Task Test2()
{
    return Task.Run(await () => 
    {
        await Task1();
        Task2();
    });
}
```

The second approach might be convenient if you want to make sure that your asynchronous `Task1()` *is started* on background thread.